# BlackBerry SDK10 + Cordova IOS + IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation crash on IpadOS 16 beta 7 after Black Berry Auth

Tags: ios, cordova

my cordova ios app crashing show me this error on IpadOS 16 Beta 7:

int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate"); EXC_BAD_ACCESS

cordova ios 6.2.0
BlackBerry SDK10
IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation latest version

it was working on ipadOs 16 Beta4 but not on beta7.

Any solutions?

Comment: You're talking about issues on a beta OS...

Comment: yes Eric, the app is working on ipados 16 beta4 but crash on beta7